# how can I call cookie in php?

Tags: php, cookies

I try create a cookie and then test it via this code:

```
define('COOKIE_ID', 'id');
define('COOKIE_EXPIRE', 0);
define('COOKIE_PATH', '');
define('DOMAIN', 'localhost');
define('COOKIE_SSL', false);
define('COOKIE_HTTPONLY', true);

public function SetCookieLive($name = COOKIE_VALUE, $value= null, $expire = COOKIE_EXPIRE, $path = COOKIE_PATH, $domain= DOMAIN, $secure=COOKIE_SSL, $httponly= COOKIE_HTTPONLY) 
    { 
    setcookie(COOKIE_ID, '123', $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);
    if(isset($_COOKIE[COOKIE_ID]))
     return true;   
        else 
     return false;
}
```

but it return me flase always...

I tested it with a simple cookie and it works.
but what is wrong with this function?

Comment: *"how can I call cookie in php?"* - That almost sounds like joke. Ok I'll bite, what do you call a cookie in PHP?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @fred Please do not spam

Comment: *sheeshhh*, it's called a "sense of humour". Spam is........ oh never mind. (something I ate last night). That's what us artists have to live on.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` will be populated with the next request, not right after calling `setcookie()`.

Comment: my sentiments exactly ^

Comment: @Fred-ii- something *crackable*.

Comment: @AlanMachado and in this case, something *"smackable"*, as in *facepalm, what have I done?*